# How to prevent other applications from changing my NSWindow frame

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm implementing an NSWindow with its own snapping behavior, and other set of features that differ slightly from a standard window.

When using assistive software like BetterSnapTool, dragging the NSWindow to the edges triggers the snapping of BetterSnapTool, interfering with my NSWindow's snapping.

How do I prevent other applications, like BetterSnapTool, from trying to modify my NSWindow's frame?

Comment: This would seem like a question for the authors of BetterSnapTool, no?  Hard to see what anybody here will be able to tell you about this, since the answer will depend upon how BetterSnapTool is implemented internally (and might depend on the version of BetterSnapTool, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I figured a solution for this. It's more of a tailored solution for this specific scenario, but hopefully it will be useful to others.

To prevent BetterSnapTool and others from modifying the frame of your `NSWindow` as you move it, you can prevent resizing on the window while the user is dragging the window, then reset the mask after the movement is done.

When handling notification `NSWindowWillMoveNotification`, you can remove the `NSResizableWindowMask` from the style mask of the NSWindow:

```
self.styleMask &= ~NSResizableWindowMask;
```

Then, on the handler of notification `NSWindowDidMoveNotification`, you can restore the style mask.

```
self.styleMask |= NSResizableWindowMask;
```

The exact implementation may differ depending on how custom your window dragging behavior is. In my case, I have custom dragging behavior depending on mouse events and I modify the window's mask on the right `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` events.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't.

Even if there is a way to limit external interference with your app's windows, blocking this kind of external modifications would probably mess up other behaviors like Mission Control.